# enviar todos los valores por ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Lo que trato de hacer es enviar la respuesta de una petición pero no recibo los valores del array solo recibo la palabra array

// archivo js donde recibo la respuesta

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("hola");
let selectCards =$('#cards');  
let selectEstados =  $('#estados');
let columna = 'commerce_brand';
//let selectCards = document.querySelector('#cards');

function cargarOpciones (idSelectIndependiente, columna, idSelectDependiente){
console.log(idSelectIndependiente);
console.log("entrando");

 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'cargar_estados.php',
        data:{
                'peticion': 'idSelectIndependiente',
                'num':columna
            }
        //dataType:'json'
    })

    .done(function(lista_rep1){
        
        console.log(lista_rep1);




         // idSelectIndependiente.empty();
         // idSelectIndependiente.append('<option value="">Elige una opcion</option>');
         // idSelectIndependiente.html('<option value="lista_rep1[i][commerce_brand]">lista_rep1[commerce_brand]</option>');
         for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {
            
            //myObj.cars[i];
        // idSelectIndependiente.append("<option value='lista_rep1[i][commerce_brand]'>lista_rep1[i][commerce_brand]</option>");
       // idSelectIndependiente.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i]['commerce_brand']+'">'+lista_rep1[i][1]+'</option>');
    
        console.log(lista_rep1);
        };
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('error al cargar las listas');
    });
console.log("saliendo");
}

cargarOpciones(selectCards, columna)
```

```html
// archivo php donde recibo los datos de la petición ajax y envio una respuesta.
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

$cards = $_POST['peticion'];
$columna = $_POST['num'];
//echo $columna;




function getData($idSelect = false, $columna){
    
    switch ($columna){
        case 'commerce_brand':
            $con = getCon();
            $query = "SELECT commerce_brand FROM `commerc` group by commerce_brand";
            $result = $con->query($query);
            $row = $result->fetch_array();

            //$listas = json_encode($row);
            /// while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
               // $listas.=" ";
               // $listas  .= $row[commerce_brand];
                //}

            //
            return $row;
        break;
        
        default:
            $probando = "viene por defecto";
        return $probando;
    }
}

echo getData($cards,$columna);
```

Comment: Te marca algún error en la consola? o en el network?

Comment: Intenta con `return json_encode($row)`

Comment: ya probé anteriormente con el json_encode pero me trae un json no valido o no recomendado por que repite las claves

Comment: No me da error solo que recibo la palabra Array y ya mas no un array con los valores que vienen de la db

Comment: Si la petición Ajax espera un JSON, en el PHP **no puedes devolver absolutamente nada que no sea un JSON**. Eso implica que tienes que: 1. Modificar el `default`, poniendo por ejemplo: `$probando = array("error"=>"viene por defecto");`.  2. Modificar el `echo`. Puedes ponerlo así:  `$json=getData($cards,$columna);` Siempre es bueno poner esto: `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` y finalmente: `echo json_encode($json);`  That's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código.

Los enumero en su orden de aparición y al final propongo una corrección:

- Debes controlar las variables que recibes en el POST
- Debes ser coherente en la respuesta. Si Ajax espera un JSON, no puedes poner una cadena como haces en el `default`.
- Tampoco puedes sacar nada más por pantalla, solamente el JSON. Eso quiere decir que cualquier archivo que incluyas, como este `require_once 'conexion.php';` no puede sacar nada por pantalla, ni mensajes de error ni nada, ni siquiera un espacio en blanco. Eso debe quedar clarísimo. Muchísima gente yerra de ese modo.
- Conviene poner un encabazado de que el contenido es JSON
- Y devolver finalmente eso que Ajax espera, un JSON.

Dicho eso, propongo este código:

```
<?php
    /*Verificamos los datos posteados usando ternarios*/
    $cards =   (empty($_POST['peticion'])) ? NULL : $_POST['peticion'];
    $columna = (empty($_POST['num'])) ?      NULL : $_POST['num'];   
    //echo $columna;  Esto no lo hagas ni de broma, ningún echo de nada
    /*Si están nulos no hacemos require ni llamamos el código para hacer nada*/
    if ($cards && $columna){
        require_once 'conexion.php';  //¿Seguro que este archivo no tiene ninguna salida por pantalla?
        $json=getData($cards,$columna);
    }else{
        $json=array("error"=>"No hay datos en el POST");    
    }
    /*
        *Pase lo que pase este código devuelve un JSON
        *es lo que Ajax espera
    */
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($json);
    
    function getData($idSelect = false, $columna){
        switch ($columna){
            case 'commerce_brand':
                $con = getCon();
                $query = "SELECT commerce_brand FROM `commerc` group by commerce_brand";
                $result = $con->query($query);

                /*
                   *Si la consulta trae más de una fila
                   *hay que abrir un bucle para leer cada fila
                */
                while ($datos = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
                    $row[]=$datos;
                }
                return $row;
            break;
            
            default:
                $probando = array ("error"=>"La columna $columna no está admitida");
                return $probando;
        }
    }
?>
```

---

#### Otros motivos por los que una petición Ajax con JSON falla

- Porque los datos vienen mal codificados de la base de datos y eso crea un json erróneo a veces
- Porque estás enviando la petición al archivo equivocado

Comment: Gracias el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente {0: "MASTERCARD", commerce_brand: "MASTERCARD"} pero en base de datos esta visa también osea al resultado le falta mostrar un valor, si recorro el vector desde php si me muestrado pero cuando envie ese mismo array solo veo la primera posicion del vector

Comment: @javier ese es un problema en cuanto a la forma de leer los resultados. Cuando la consulta trae varias filas hay que abrir un bucle (en este caso `while`) para leer los resultados fila por fila y guardarlos en un array por ejemplo. He modificado el código implementando eso, lo puedes ver, he puesto un comentario en esa parte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda .Pense que podía enviar el resultado directamente sin recorrerlo y guardar sus valores en un array pero ya vi por las malas que no se puede. Pude resolver mi problema gracias a tu ayuda. Saludos

Comment: @javier de nada. Si fuera una sola fila sí, pero si son varias filas y no abres el bucle, sólo atrapas la primera fila. Eso es lógico, PHP lo hace así sobre todo para evitar problemas de memoria en consultas que puedan arrojar muchos datos. No los trae de golpe, sino que abre como un puntero para recorrer fila por fila. Algo así como una cadena de producción. Los productos van entrando uno por uno por donde pasa la cadena (y por donde pasa la cadena es un pequeño agujero, no un boquete donde caben cientos o miles de productos, lo cual sería una locura desde todo punto de vista).